# Alternative to if elseif in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, if-statement

I have a character string called `name`. The third character in `name` is a letter that indicates which month `name` is associated to, according to the following scheme:

```
Jan  F
Feb  G
Mar  H
Abr  J
May  K
Jun  M
Jul  N
Aug  Q
Sep  U
Oct  V
Nov  X
Dec  Z
```

I want to rename the files that `name` identifies, so that instead of the arbitrary letter system, I use numbers:

```
01
02
 ...
12
```

To do this I used if/elseif in the following way:

```
 if name(3) == 'F'                      
            monthdesignator = '01';
        elseif name(3) == 'G'
            monthdesignator = '02';
        elseif name(3) == 'H'
            monthdesignator = '03';
        elseif name(3) == 'J'
            monthdesignator = '04';
        elseif name(3) == 'K'
            monthdesignator = '05';
        elseif name(3) == 'M'
            monthdesignator = '06';
        elseif name(3) == 'N'
            monthdesignator = '07';
        elseif name(3) == 'Q'
            monthdesignator = '08';
        elseif name(3) == 'U'
            monthdesignator = '09';
        elseif name(3) == 'V'
            monthdesignator = '10';
        elseif name(3) == 'X'
            monthdesignator = '11';
        else
            monthdesignator = '12';   
        end

 newfilename=strcat('C:\TickDataMinuteBars\MinuteBarsCsv\',name(1),name(2),'20',name(4),name(5),monthdesignator,'.csv');
```

but this is so unwieldy and repetitive. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use a [hashmap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) (this option is the fastest and most concise):

```
% Define your table once.
keys = {'F','G','H','J','K','M','N','Q','U','V','X','W'};
values = {'01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'};
lookup = containers.Map(keys,values,'UniformValues', true);

% Lookups run in constant O(1) time.
month = lookup(name(3));
```

**Option 2:** Use [case statements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html), which is marginally better than `if/else`:

```
switch name(3)
  case 'F', month = '01';
  case 'G', month = '02';
  case 'H', month = '03';
  ...
  otherwise, month = '12';
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a switch-case statment at matlab. You can read about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html)